# Android app working with Firebase doesn't work on my Nokia 5

Tags: android, firebase

Just started learning how to work with `Firebase` on `Android Studio` and I created a simple login/signup app to test on my Nokia 5 but when I try to sign up, nothing happens. The app starts with a login page and at the bottom there's a `TextView` that links the user to the signup page if they don't have an account. In the sign up page there's an email `EditText` box and password `EditText` box then a button to signup and a `TextView` to direct the user to login page. When the user registers, a toast should pop up indicating successful signup. Unfortunately, nothing happens when clicking signup button.

Here's the code for the signup activity:

```
package com.godiegodie.firebaseuser;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    EditText etEmail, etPassword;

    public FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        findViewById(R.id.Signupbtn).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.tvLogin).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void registerUser(){
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(email.isEmpty()){
            etEmail.setError("Email is required");
            etEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            etEmail.setError("Please enter a valid email");
            etEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(password.isEmpty()){
            etPassword.setError("Password is required");
            etPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(password.length()<6){
            etPassword.setError("Password should contain minimum of 6 characters");
            etPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Registration is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Registration failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){

            case R.id.Signupbtn:
                registerUser();
                break;

            case R.id.tvLogin:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you enabled email/password in the firebase console ? @Godwin

Comment: @A.N.T yes I have.

Comment: have you added the internet permission too ?

Comment: @A.N.T how do I go about that?

Comment: Is there a stack trace or any other useful information in the app's logcat?

Comment: something like this    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> @ Godwin

Comment: @A.N.T I feel like an idiot. Thanks for the help tho

Comment: you welcome bro.

Comment: @A.N.T damn it. Sorry dude but that didn't work

Comment: I keep getting user registration failure

Comment: 12-09 16:36:54.584 27218-27346/com.godiegodie.firebaseuser V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Comment: I got that error in logcat @ScottKronheim

Comment: Did you follow all the Android setup instructions?  Do you have a google-services.json file in your app folder?  See https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup.

Comment: have you also try it on a different phone ?@ Godwin

Comment: @ScottKronheim I used the Firebase Assistant

Comment: @A.N.T Yes I have. An old Lg E440 running Android 4.1

Comment: can you post your manifest @ Godwin